# How should I resolve an ERROR occuring while compiling Assets (Laravel Mix)

Tags: php, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I am not new with **PHP**, but I am a total beginner with PHP frameworks.
Recently I have started learning **Laravel** framework for **PHP**, so I decided to start with tutorials from Traversy Media channel. After I have tried to compile assets I got an ERROR: (**An error occurs after npm run dev**)

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:164:11
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:231:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:228:27)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:134:21)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\postcss-loader\lib\index.js:145:8)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 4:14-254
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

I am trying to solve this problem but without success. I have tried to rebuild node-sass, also I've tried to reinstall all dependencies and change my @import path and nothing solved an error.
This is the code that refers to an error that occurs in **C:\xampp\myapp\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:164:11**
```

[Resolve function for referring error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUZX.png)

If you could help me with this i would really appreciate it, because I really need to speed up my learning process.

npm -v 6.1.0
node -v 8.11.3
composer -v 1.7.2
artisan --version (Laravel Framework) 5.7.13

Comment: Always post error messages as text, not images.  Otherwise they are hard for people to copy and unable to be searched.

Comment: You also may want to upgrade your node version.  The latest LTS is 10.13.  You're quite behind.  Always make sure you're on an updated version if you're using the latest version of laravel mix.

Comment: @Devon Thank you for your suggestions. I will update my node, do you think that node version is an actual problem causing an error?

Comment: Edit your question, and your errors as text, not images.

Comment: @Lucky, not sure, it's just always a good idea to run the latest node version when using mix.  Since it's a browser query issue, what's your environment and which browsers are installed in that environment?

Comment: @Devon I am using Windows 7, running an Apache Server, and I am writing my code in Visual Studio Code, also using bash integrated terminal. I am not completely sure what do you mean by which browsers are installed, can you clarify that? For testing my app I am using Google Chrome, if you meant that?

Answer (score 0):

if npm install generate to much file in your root project
go to C:\user{yourname} and empty .npmrc file (your will find prefix= something)

Second i resolve this issue by deleting node_modules and

```
"browserslist": [
        "last 3 versions"
    ],
```

in my package.json.

You run again npm install and npm run watch or dev